# Azure pipelines yml validation error; did not find expected '-' indicator; while calling template

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I get an yml template error while referencing a template from azure-pipelines.yml.
I've validated the YML in several online editors and it is valid (per them and me). Moreover, when I move the template step into the `azure-pipeline.yml` it works like a charm.

This is my code:

```
# azure-pipeline.yml
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: git
      name: azure-devops-reusable-tasks

steps:
  - template: maven-package-owasp-scan.yml@templates
```

```
# maven-package-owasp-scan.yml@templates
stages:
  - stage: Build
    displayName: Build
    jobs:
      - job: Pacakge
        steps:
          - bash: mvn -e package
            displayName: mvn package
          - task: dependency-check-build-task@6
            displayName: Owasp dependency check
            inputs:
              projectName: $(Build.Repository.Name)
              scanPath: '**/*.*'
              format: 'HTML'
```

At first I had just the steps sequence in the latter template. This gave the same error.
The error in question:

```
Encountered error(s) while parsing pipeline YAML:
/maven-package-owasp-scan.yml@templates: (Line: 3, Col: 5, Idx: 40) - (Line: 3, Col: 5, Idx: 40): While parsing a block collection, did not find expected '-' indicator.
```

The error happens when I try and run the pipeline. Once I select the resources tab, it tries to validate the yml and it produces the error.

[image: Producing the error while clicking resources tab]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above work was done on a feature branch. There was an error in the master branch. When trying to run the pipeline and clicking resources, it scanned master branch by default. When fixing the indentation error on the master branch (which above error was referring to, it just didn't say which branch) the problem was solved.